# Syncing data between 2 SQL Server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 servers. One used for backup as well as sharing with other external users and the other for live queries internally.

At the moment, on the backup database, the existing table is dropped and new table is added using the below code:-

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[test]
SELECT * INTO test FROM [remote server].[remote database].[dbo].[remote table];
```

Is there another method instead of dropping and adding tables. Ideally, something that looks for any changes and syncs them using SQL Server Management Studio.

Edit:
My server is Express Edition and remote is SQL Standard

Comment: Several, ranging from `INSERT SELECT ..` with left outer joins to Change tracking to [full-featured replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2017). Dropping and using `SELECT ... INTO` is never used for such operations because you lose indexes. TRUNCATE and INSERT SELECT everything is sometimes used if there's not a lot of data.

Comment: BTW you don't need to "back up" data like this at all. SQL Server provides [database mirroring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/database-mirroring-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) since 2005. DB mirroring is available in all editions. The latest versions replace it with Always-On, essentially a mirroring+clustering solution

Comment: Why do you drop the table?  How does the internal table get populated?

Comment: Transactional replication would be the a sensible choice.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sync two tables in simplex communication way(One Directional) then you should go with transaction replication.
Sync will be performed on transaction commit for particular row.